# Weird error while trying to install python3.5-dev on ubuntu 16.04.6

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, dependencies

I'm trying to do an offline install of some deb packages on a new Ubuntu machine:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

I downloaded all the deb dependencies recursively in another computer, ssh'd into this computer (that is only connected to internal network) and tried to install the package using `sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev`

- I created a source file for apt and overwrote the `/etc/apt/sources.list` to have only my file: **deb file:/home/*/*/debs ./**
- After that I `sudo apt-get update`

That shuold have made the installation flow go like this:

- Run apt-get install
- apt checks in sources.list
- apt finds the Packgez.gz file I have there
- apt finds all deb dependencies in `debs` dir
- apt installs dependencies and then installs the actual package

However, for some reason, I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.5-dev : Depends: python3.5 (= 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.9) but 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.5 is to be installed
                 Depends: libpython3.5-dev (= 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.9) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libpython3.5 (= 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.9) but 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.5 is to be installed
```

From what I understand, Ubuntu 16.04.6 is actually the 16.10 backport to 16.04. Hence, AFAIU, 16.04.9 is a newer version and needs dependencies in order to be installed.

Is that true? The thing that bothers me in this explanation is that the dependencies download was done with this command ([SO src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008193/how-to-list-download-the-recursive-dependencies-of-a-debian-package)) from a computer with 16.04.6, thus, it should have included all of the dependencies:

```
$ apt-cache depends --recurse --no-recommends --no-suggests --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances <your-package-here> | grep "^\w" | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

never mess-up with default python version, because many system pacakges depend on them

If you need specific version, use pyenv

Comment: I don't, and that's not related